# Is there a way to override setTimeout function so it uses microseconds instead of milliseconds

Tags: javascript

Since there is this function `window.performance.now()` that returns the current time in microseconds since the page started to load, is there a way to implement it's accuracy in to a more precise `setTimeout` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no, there isn't.  In addition, the millisecond granularity of `setTimeout` is misleading.  [Some browsers are far less accurate](http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/), although [there are workarounds for this](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-accurate-timers-in-javascript/).  In any case, `setTimeout` calls are only called after the current call stack finishes executing, which could be much longer than you want.  `setInterval` actually has an interesting behavior where it will queue up multiple calls if they're deferred by other executing code, so that when they execute they'll all execute one after another with no delay in between.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:no.

Long answer: Javascript doesn't guarantee an exact time-out period, just a minimum time-out period. Both `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` defer the code and execute it when the thread becomes available. Measuring this to microseconds would be pointless.